# Sharing Data between Resolvers

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql, apollo-server

Can any one help me on the way to share data between different resolvers in graphql. One approach is to use context but in many places in the web it was mentioned that avoid mutating the context.

i.e For example i have a schema as below

```
 type Person{
    ID:Int
    Name: String
    Age: String
    address: Address
}

type Address{
    
    address-line1: String   
    address-line2: String   
    City: String    
    Country: String
    Pincode:String

}


type Query{
    
    GetpersonbyID(id: int):Person
    GetPersons: [Person]

}
```

Now for example, to pass some additional information to address resolver from root resolver currently i am using context.Is this the right approach or is there a better way to achieve this.

Comment: Please provide additional context around what you're trying to do. Do you need to pass down data from a "parent" field resolver to a "child" field resolver? It would be helpful to show the relevant parts of your schema and your code and explain exactly what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Modified the question by providing a sample scenario

Answer (score 0):

You can just return the necessary information inside your root resolver:

```
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    getPersonById: (root, args) => {
      const person = await getPerson(args.id)
      person.address = {
        foo: 'bar',
      }
      return person
    },
  },
  Address: {
    addressLine1: (address) => {
      console.log(address) // { foo: 'bar' }
    },
  },
}
```

Comment: For Passing data i am good with this approach.But for example if i want to pass some additional details like  count of records present in parent data , then  as per this approach i need to add count attribute for all the records in parent. Instead of this is there a better way of doing this and also is it ok to use context for such cases

Comment: It sounds like you should be handling this further down your stack (i.e. inside `getPerson` in the example code) rather than inside GraphQL.

Comment: Yeah currently i am doing this get personby id code , by attaching the count attribute to context.Is it ok to attach custom information to context?